# Button self "rearranging"

Tags: android, layout

Wondering how I do build a layout with self rearranging button, when the user turns his device from portrait to landscape, using relativelayout ?

I do not want to use scrolling on my layout and I have a lot of buttons

Answer (score 2):

You can provide two different main.xml (or any layout xml file) Place one in res/layout/ and one in res/layout-land/ When the device switches orientation the system will handle the "magic" of switching to the appropriate file.

---

Here is [some documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about supporting these type of behaviors...

Comment: How, this was so easy. I thought I had to use relative or smthg like that.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopheCVB, don't know why I didn't think to add that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly what you are looking to do is have one layout displayed for portrait mode and another for landscape mode. This is actually fairly easy to accomplish.

Here is a link to a quick tutorial:
[How to change your layout in Android landscape / portrait mode](http://www.tekkie.ro/quick-n-dirty/how-to-change-your-layout-in-android-landscape-portrait-mode/)